# Angular making a CORS request

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am very confused.  I am trying to use a web service to obtain data.  When I put the url into the browser, it works great and returns the json I was expecting.

If angular is a client side framework, why does it not succeed when making the exact same request?  The is coming from my browser but the receiving domain still barfs on it.

What am I missing?

Comment: please share more details about the web service and its request / response headers for this call.

Comment: This is a browser security feature, your web service needs to implement CORS. Post which technology stack you are using for the webservice and we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever owns the service needs to configure CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), to either allow your particular domain access to the service or to allow all domains to access the service. You then need to configure the correct headers to send your origin and credentials to the origin you are trying to access the service on when making the request so that it can decide if it's gonna let you hit that endpoint or reject the request. Here's the go-to website for an overview and setup guide for CORS: http://enable-cors.org/.

You also need to set the `withCredentials` flag to true on the http request config object.

Ex.

```
$http({
    url : 'url of service',
    method : "POST",
    data : {
        test : name
    },
    withCredentials : true,
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
});
```

More about the angular configuration for this can be found on the angular docs website for the $http service.

Comment: You only need to set withCredentials= true if you are using an HttpAuth method.  If you're going to use "withCredentials" client-side, you also have to use "SupportsCredentials" server-side so that the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is enabled...otherwise "withCredentials" will do nothing good.  Where did you hear that "withCredentials" was required for a CORS request?

Comment: @K.AlanBates feel free to post a different answer